# Finding an average of last 3 numbers of array

Tags: c++

I need to find an average of last three array's numbers. I tried using this code but something seems to be wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[10];
    int n, sum = 0, kiek = 0;
    double avg;
    cin >> n;
    for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
        sum = sum + a[i];
        kiek++;
    }
    avg = (a[n] + a[n-1] + a[n-2]) / 3.;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(3) << avg;
    return 0;
}
```

This is the input:

> 5
>   
>   1 2 3 4 5

This is the output I get:

> 3.000

This is the output I want:

> 4.000

Comment: Remember with 0 indexing `a[n]` is 1 past the end of the array.

Comment: It's the outputs i'm supposed to get. Instead of 4 I get 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access an element which is out of bound of array, in the line

> `avg=(a[n]+a[n-1]+a[n-2])/3.;`

try using
`avg = (a[n-1]+a[n-2]+a[n-3])/3.;`

And also make sure that 'n' doesn't get value greater than 10, as your size of array is 10.

Comment: Care should also be take to not get a `n` value less than `3` (or to handle it gracefully some other way).